# Listbox items and selected Item

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a Form with a ListBox and a Database-class. The Form calls a method from the Database which returns a string.

```
public listItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Db = new Database();
        itemList = new List<string>();
        showAllItems();
    }
```

Now, the showAllItems-function calls the Db.getAllitems() function which returns a List.

```
private void showAllItems()
    {
        itemList = Db.getAllItems();
        lb_itemList.DataSource = itemList;
    }
```

The List displays the names of all items in the listbox. But, I also want to return the description of the items. But I don't want the description to be displayed in the listbox. I want it to be displayed on a label next to the listBox, which shows the description of the selected Item.

My main problem is, that I don't know how to return multiple data without displaying all the data in the listbox. I just want the name in the listbox and the other data to be displayed next to the listbox on label dependent on the selected Item from the ListBox

```
    public List<string> getAllItems()
    {
        List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=HCI.db");
        connection.Open();

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT rid, name, category, price, status, specific FROM items", connection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //itemList.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetInt64(rid)));
                itemList.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name")));
                itemList.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("category")));
                itemList.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("price")));
                itemList.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("status")));
                itemList.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("specific")));

            }
        }
        connection.Close();
        return itemList;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another List that contains your class and get the items from the list whenever you select an item in the listbox.

```
public class YourClass{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public List<YourClass> getAllItems()
{
List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=HCI.db");
connection.Open();

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT rid, name, category, price, status, specific FROM items", connection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //itemList.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetInt64(rid)));
        itemList.Add(new YourClass(){
      Id = reader.GetString(reader.GetInt64("Id")),
      Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name")),
      Description = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("desc")),
      Price = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("price"))
});               

    }
}
connection.Close();
return itemList;

}

//in your selectedindexchanged event
private void lb_itemList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lb_itemList.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
          var item = lb_itemList.SelectedItem as YouClass;
          if (item != null)
          {
                lblDescription.Text = item.Description;
                lblPrice.Text = item.Price
          }
    }
 }
```

Comment: So you mean, I leave it like that. Just get the name with this method and then write another method which gets the ID depended on the selected item in the ListBox and gets the rest of the data? If yes, how can I afterwards get specific data from the List<string>? Let's say I save description and the price in this list, how can I especially call only the desc or the price?

Comment: If that's the case you can create a class containing all your required info and use it to create a list instead of string. I've edited my answer above to show how to create a custom class then binding them directly to your listbox.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom `Class` like this:

```
public class Item 
{
     public string Name;
     public string Description;
}
```

then change your return method:

```
public List<Item> getAllItems()
{
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=HCI.db");
        connection.Open();

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT rid, name, category, price, status, specific FROM items", connection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //itemList.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetInt64(rid)));
                var item = new Item();
                item.Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name"));
                item.Description = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("specific"))
                itemList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
        return itemList;
}
```

And bind it to your list like that:

```
private void showAllItems()
{
        itemList = Db.getAllItems();
        lb_itemList.DisplayMember = "Name";
        lb_itemList.DataSource = itemList;
}
```

and last implement `SelectedIndexChanged` event to handle description label:

```
private void lb_itemList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (lb_itemList.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
              var item = lb_itemList.SelectedItem as Item;
              if (item != null)
              {
                    lblDescription.Text = item.Description;
              }
        }
}
```